# Find a string in a vector in c++

Tags: c++

I have a vector of string , and I want to return a string from vector which is similar to a string.

For example vector contains: "load", "fox", "google", "firefox" and the string is: "mozilla firefox". The true result in this sample is "firefox".

I use the code below, but it is wrong and returns "fox" for my sample.

```
vector<string>::const_iterator it_found = find_if(MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end(), [&MyString](string s) -> bool 
{ return( MyString.find(s) != string::npos ); });

if(it_found != MyVector.end())
{
    //Do Somthing
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: you only check if the 'string inside the vector' is part of the searched string. so your condition is not specific enough

Comment: Both `"fox"` and `"firefox"` are in `"mozilla firefox"`. You need additional criteria to choose `"firefox"` and ignore `"fox"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the first string that is a substring of your search term. It seems you want the best match, so a more sophisticated approach is needed. You could calculate some score how good the match is and find the element that gives the maximum score, e.g. with `std::max_element`

The score could be simply the length of the matched substring or something more complicated if you later improve your matching algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the input string on whitespace using this implementation of `split` returning a `std::vector<std::string>`.

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string const &input) { 
    std::istringstream buffer(input);
    std::vector<std::string> ret((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(buffer)), 
                                 std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
    return ret;
}
```

Then compare each string in `MyVector` with the candidates from the returned vector from `split`.

```
std::string MyString = "mozzilla firefox";
std::vector<std::string> MyVector = {"fire", "fox", "firefox", "mozilla"};
auto candidates = split(MyString);
auto it_found = std::find_if(MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end(), [&candidates](std::string s) -> bool{  
  return (std::find(candidates.begin(), candidates.end(), s) != candidates.end()); 
}); 

if(it_found != MyVector.end()){
  std::cout<<"\nFound : "<<*it_found;
}
```

Output :

```
Found : firefox
```

Note that this only finds the first match of strings in `MyVector`with a string in the `candidates`.